# Matching, event study and cohort data

Tags: matching, generalized-did

I have merged data to create an event study for the treated population. This treatment happens in 4 batches for some university students in certain cohorts (when they turn 19 in 2005 and are at university when the treatment commenced - thus are treated. But this treatment doesn’t happen for a majority of students and for a variety of cohorts. I have tried running an event study but run into issues of colinearity, so I think i may turn to matching, as the treatment happens (especially the first treatment for higher tier universities). so it may be better to match on all characteristics bar treatment. Is this a fitting way to avoid colinearity in event studies (matching on observables) so that the treatment effect is found via matching. Furthermore, what type of matching would be best here (there are more control than there are treat but obviously some universities are different) so exact matching, nearest neighbour matching, propensity score or fancy genetic matching? the cohorts i have are different birth years and thus attended university at different years but this isn’t exactly specified in the data just estimated.